# Need help making jQuery Transit transition repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

```
// IGNORE THIS CODE
$(document).ready(function(){       
  $("#sticky-header").hide();
});
// IGNORE THIS CODE
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/de74ezo5/14/

So what I was trying to achieve here was to make the pink header collapse and stay fixed at the top of the page after scrolling past the top red header. I am using Transit with jQuery to create the transition (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). I don't know a more efficient way; Easing doesn't satisfy my needs.

The transition, for some reason, isn't repeating after scrolling back to the top, and then past the red header again.

This is what I need help with:

1. How do I make the transition repeat after scrolling back to the top, and then past the red header again?
2. How can I adjust the speed of the transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `sticky-header` div's css is getting a `transform:` rule added to it on initial scroll down. When you scroll back up, this rule remains even though you hide it (which only changes `display:block` to `display:none`)

**Page Load:**

```
<div id="sticky-header" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**Scroll down:**

```
<div id="sticky-header" style="display: block; **transform**: translate(0px, 60px);"></div>
```

**Scroll back up:** You can see transform is still there even though display = none

```
<div id="sticky-header" style="display: none; **transform**: translate(0px, 60px);"></div>
```

**Scroll back down:** Rule already fired, will not re-fire unless removed.

```
<div id="sticky-header" style="display: block; **transform**: translate(0px, 60px);"></div>
```

In your else, you need to alter the css and remove that transform rule so that it refires:

```
    $('#sticky-header').css({
        "display" : "none",
        "transform" : ""        
    });
```

**Also, side performance note:**

Every time your window scrolls below 160px, your transition is fired. You can see here as I keep scrolling lower and lower, the event is repeatedly fired (you can see it ran 6 times as I mouse wheeled down the page)

[image]

Add a check in there so `.transition` is only fired once: You can do this with jQuery data:

```
  $(document).data('scrolled', false);
```

Full code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sticky-header").hide();
            $(document).data('scrolled', false);
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(document).scrollTop() > 160 ) { // do transition
                if (!$(document).data('scrolled')) {
                    $('#sticky-header').show();
                    $("#sticky-header").transition({ y: 60 });      
                    $(document).data('scrolled', true);
                }
            }
            else { //show original header
                $('#sticky-header').css({
                    "display" : "none",
                    "transform" : ""        
                });
                $(document).data('scrolled', false);
            }
        });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/de74ezo5/15/)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I am trying to think of another way to make it more efficient. I was thinking about using jQuery Waypoints with animate.css: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

But I am having issues setting it up.